# Eclipse webapp structure

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The project structure in Eclipse:

[image]

When I try to remove the `src - main - webapp` them Eclipse says that the content of `src/main/java` also will be removed.
How can I safely move the content from `src - main - webapp` into WebContent folder?

Comment: Why would you want to move the files that are in the right place at `src/main/webapp`, to the wrong place of `WebContent`?

Comment: @Tunaki because the all new eclipse webapp projects contais their content in the WebContent folder

Comment: Yes they do, but all Maven projects should have their web content inside `src/main/webapp`. See the [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: What you have there is a standard Maven project structure, and Eclipse can use that structure. Moving the webapp folder elsewhere will break your Maven build for no reason.

Comment: @JBNizet but there is a way to covert maven project into eclipse-maven project by `eclipse:eclipse` is not it?

Comment: Import the maven project into eclipse, and you should be ready to go.

Comment: Don't use `eclipse:eclipse`, that plugin is discontinued and doesn't behave nicely with Eclipse at all. Use m2e, which should be installed by default on the Java EE version of Eclipse.